# Html / Email / Distribution list problem from a noob

Tags: html, database

I need to create a feature for a website that will allow a user to enter their email in order to receive a free promotion (which will be emailed immediately) and be added to an announcement list. I haven't done any web programming and am wondering where I should start?
Should I just create a database and everytime an email is entered, add the email to the database, then when I want to send out an announcement just write a script that will send an email to every address?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sites like [Campaigner](http://www.campaigner.com/) do all of this for you. Why re-invent the wheel.

Comment: phplist is another example, which you can run on your server, rather then paying someone else to run it. It is free, but of course requires more work to get it set up, etc.

Comment: Yes  I agree, probably best to use another service to handle this for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use emailing list software; on a Linux box, that would be Mailman, http://www.list.org/.

Answer (score 0):

Use ASP.NET express. Configure send e-mail and sore whatever you need in the database.

http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/brad/sending-email-from-asp-net-4-c-sample-code/